# Horizontal picker for Android

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, picker

I'd like to create a **Horizontal picker** as shown in the picture below but, I can not:

[image: Picker]

This picker is vertical: 
[image: Vertical picker]

I want 3 pickers. For example: in the first, there is the list of houses and in the second, I find bedroom, kitchen...

Comment: which type of picker you want?please clarify your Question in brief

Comment: @dipali  I want  3 picker:
for example in the first there is the list of houses
and in the second i find bathroom, bedroom, kitchen ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using  [GalleryView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) for something like this.I don't know any other view can be used for this purpose even `GalleryView` is **depreciated**.

Gallery view bounces the selected item to center of view and snaps to every item after scrolling.

You can also use a horizontal `ListView` implementation but you have to handle scroll and bounces yourself.